# Email Notifications for Risks and Issues in PWA

Tags: project-online, pwa

I want to be able to set up e-mail notifications when someone is assigned to an issue or risk in PWA. 
The closest I've gotten is "Manage my resources' alerts and reminders" under "My personal settings" but there isn't anything on setting up alerts for Risks and Issues (only for tasks, resource requests and status reports).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unforthunatlly, In Project server, you can't manage the Risk and Issue alerts from Personal Settings > The Alerts and Reminders.

[image]

This is because the Risk and Issue are SharePoint lists that are a part of Project site, that means you can't manage its alerts via PWA settings and you will need to manage its alerts manually as you have done for any list in SharePoint via

- Alert ME, For more details, check , [Setting up an alert for Project Site Issue (and Risk) Alerts using Alert Me](http://prasannaadavi.com/2011/07/setting-up-an-alert-for-project-site-issue-and-risk-alerts-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow.html#.WFJsafl96Ul)

[image]

- Custom Workflow. For more details check,[Setting up an alert for Project Site Issue (and Risk) Alerts using SharePoint Designer Workflow](http://prasannaadavi.com/2011/07/setting-up-an-alert-for-project-site-issue-and-risk-alerts-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow-2.html#.WFJr8fl96Uk)